# How to determine the maximum charging output of a QI wireless charging coil and circuit board?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c, wireless-charging, usb-pd

I purchased a 20-watt 3-coil QI wireless charging coil and PCB recently (see image with specs below) and I want to power it via the USB-C header and preferably a USB-C to USB-C cable. The USB port on the PCB says "QC2-3.0", so I assume that means QuickCharge 2.0 thru 3.0 compatibility, but every 12v power port USB socket adapter I can find that supports QuickCharge 3.0 (rated at 3 amps and 18 watts) has a USB-A interface. I have a good array of other 12v port power sockets with USB-C sockets, but they are all either "PD" type sockets apparently, with varying amp/watt specs. However when I plug into any of those sockets with USB-C ports the PCB will not power up. And I've tried several USB-C to USB-C cables and have confirmed that the cables are good with other devices.

I purchased a power port adapter that has a QC 4.0 USB-C socket since QC 4.0 sockets are supposed to work with QC 3.0 devices from what I understand, but still cannot get the PCB to power up.

So now I'm still wondering what is needed to get a 12v power port with a USB-C socket to power this board. Are the amps and/or wattages too high on my other power ports, to the point where the board apparently has some sort of power protection to keep the board from powering on and getting fried? What's my best way to achieve power over USB-C, and maximum the charging capacity over this type of connection? Thanks a million to anyone that is able to help!! :)

[image: 20W QI Charger]

Comment: The amp/wattage ratings on your USB power supplies are the maximums they are capable of supplying, not the value they would try to force into the device you plug into them. S the problem you're having is not related to those rating values.

Comment: Please provide a link to the product

Comment: Thanks brhans and Bruce.

I appreciate the explanation about the capability of the power supplies not being the power they are forcing, because I definitely misunderstood that.  Any ideas what else to consider?

Comment: The product listing does not give very much info on these at all unfortunately, but here is the link to it:

https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256803225210759.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.7.491e325drDUfD0&algo_pvid=8086ef21-a6a4-427c-b09a-103cb7286087&algo_exp_id=8086ef21-a6a4-427c-b09a-103cb7286087-3&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000025667828479%22%7D&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21USD%2128.18%2119.72%21%21%21%21%21%40211bf3f716788130152764160d06c0%2112000025667828479%21sea%21US%210&curPageLogUid=P4OYpelZ0i5P

Thanks for any continued help! :)

Comment: Does anyone happen to have any suggestions on this? Thanks a bunch!!!